# I making a simple quadratic equation solver in java by using the quadratic formula. This is what happened:

Tags: java

My code:

```
 int a = 1;
 int b = 6;
 int c = 5;
 double x1 = (-b + Math.sqrt(b^2 - 4*a*c))/(2*a);
 double x2 = (-b - Math.sqrt(b^2 - 4*a*c))/(2*a);
 System.out.println("x=" + x1 + x2 );
```

Output:

```
 x=NaNNan
```

Comment: You have to add the following if-statement: `if(x1+x2==NaNNan){x= Batman}`.

Answer (score 5):

`b^2` doesn't do what you think it does in Java. Write `b*b` instead. The `^` operator is actually [the bitwise-XOR operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html); there is no exponent operator. (There is, however, a [`Math.pow()` function](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow%28double,%20double%29).)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to `^` being a XOR instead of the power, your solver has another issue: sometimes, B<sup>2</sup> is less than 4AC, in which case the equation has only complex solutions. Your code should check for that condition before calling `Math.sqrt` to avoid getting a `NaN` back.

Finally, your output is incorrect: your `println` would produce the concatenation of the roots with no space in between, rather than printing them individually.

Here is your code after the fix:

```
int a = 1;
int b = 6;
int c = 5;
int d = b*b - 4*a*c;
if (d < 0) {
     System.out.println("No real solutions.");
} else {
    double sqD = Math.sqrt(d);
    double x1 = (-b + sqD)/(2*a);
    double x2 = (-b - sqD)/(2*a);
    System.out.println("x=" + x1 + " " + x2 );
}
```

Comment: `s/\brational/real/g`, `s/irrational/complex/g`

Comment: _"in which case the equation has only irrational solutions"_ .You mean complex solutions. And the output is correct since it's the same as `System.out.println(("x=" + x1) + x2 );`

Comment: @ZouZou There's no space in between, though, so for outputs that have more than three digits in total there would be some guessing in figuring out the output.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Yes I totally agree that the current output is not very convenient, just wanted to point out that _"your println would produce the sum of the roots"_ was not correct :). And +1 for pointing out the complex solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You could write `b * b` or `Math.pow(b,2)` instead of `b ^ 2`, which is the [bitwise xor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_xor#XOR) (exclusive or) of `b` with `2`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to make a trigonometric function here. Dont remember the name but i can tell that b is meant to be squared? If so, use the Math.pow(numberToSquare, theSquareNumber)
 The one line Will look like this:
Double x1 = (-b + Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b, 2) - 4*a*c))/(2*a)